# Prevent Excel from converting times into floats

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have imported tabulated data from a website using Excel's "Data > From Web". The problem is, that a time, e.g. `47:38:00`, is automatically translated. If I click on it, `01/01/1900  23:38:00` is shown in the formula textbox, and converting the data to `text` or `general` converts it to a float, `1.984722222`.

The float conversion is super annoying as this is what is presented when extracting data from the spreadsheet. Is there a way to stop Excel from manipulating the data, and just treat everything as raw?

Comment: Excel stores dates and times as days and fractions of a day since 1/1/1900.  That is what you see in the formula bar.  You can format it to show up in a worksheet cell however you wish, but you cannot change how Excel stores a date or time.  The only other option is to specify that column as text prior to importing the data.  But, of course, it won't be an Excel time, merely a text string, and you will have to implicitly or explicitly convert it to a real time before being able to format it or use it in calculations.

Comment: Thank you @RonRosenfeld for your explanation but that's a shame, in this context, that Excel works that way. Oh well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data is not changed, it is only the *Display Format* that changes.

You can set the display format you prefer; for example, for the shown `47:38:00` use the (custom) format `[hh]:mm:ss`.

The square brackets `[]` tell Excel to not go to the next higher unit - days - but stay with hours, no matter how big the number is; without the brackets, you would see `1d 23:38:00`or so. For example, using `[mm]:ss` would give you `2858:00`, in minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thanks but all I want is to be able to import raw data. I know I can fiddle around with Excel's format settings if I had the time.

Comment: @MrGoobri I think you don't understand the answer. Excel doesn't change the data, it always imports raw data.  Showing the data in default format isn't optional.  If you want to see exactly what's in the source file, you need to import column as text, but in case it'll be more difficult to perform calculations on it.